# How to remove double quotes from within a tmp file using batch scripting/cmd

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have my output in a .tmp file, the value inside is `"REG F+W"` which i have stored in a variable `VAR1`.

i have another set variable `VAR2=REG F+W`.
I need to compare the two variables `If "%VAR1%" == "VAR2" GOTO STEP1`

But since `VAR1` has got double quotes in it, its not working. How could i remove the double quotes in tmp file before putting them in the variable `VAR1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i tried this and it worked.

```
SET VAR1
SET VAR1=%VAR1:"=%
SET VAR1
```